# Deploying rails app, cant hit endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am deploying a Rails api with react front end to a AWS EC2 instance.
This is my first time doing something like this.

I run `rails s -e production` and it runs on my EC2 instance on port 3000
This makes my endpoints `ec2URL:3000/api/users/` instead of `ec2URL/api/users/`

Do I have to change app my react fetch calls to match this or is there a way to serve my routes without the `:3000`

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is react front end part of the same rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production, You need to use port 80(HTTP) or port 443(HTTPS).

Suggest you go through this [tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04).

You need an application server like Phusion-passenger and configure it with Apache/Nginx.

Comment: I have my webserver `sudo service httpd start` running on port 80 how do I run both?

Comment: @Matt updated the answer. For better understanding refer to any tutorial online.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Application load balancer from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html
You can map http port 80 to 3000 to instance using listeners and target groups.
This aslo lot more flexibility later if you want scale or add https to your API.